# post tweets from codeigniter site

Tags: php, twitter, codeigniter-2

I have a PHP site developed in codeigniter.

The users post comments on the site and I want these comments to be tweeted to the users's account. How can I do this???

I am using elliot haughin's twitter library for sign in with twitter. Can this library be helpful for making tweets???

Thanks,
Aniket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [this repository](https://github.com/vixnet/codeigniter-twitter), which is an updated version of Elliot's library. The original one is *two years old* and likely no longer actively maintained. See [`tweet_test.php`](https://github.com/vixnet/codeigniter-twitter/blob/master/application/controllers/tweet_test.php) for an example tweet to Twitter which should get you started.

Comment: i already have implemented sign in with twitter. the file tweet_test.php just shows authentication function. I need to post tweets from my site.........

Comment: @Aniket -- Yes and in the `auth()` method there's a line which posts a status: `$this->tweet->call('post', 'statuses/update', array('status' => 'Posting a status'));`

Comment: ok so if i call this method then tweets will be posted on my twitter account......this is cool....

Comment: what if i want to make a tweet to someone else's account then how can i do that???

Comment: @Aniket -- those you'll have to build methods for. See the Twitter API: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1